# How does this API endpoint validate the request is legit?

Tags: javascript, security, md5

I ran across a list of open API endpoints a while back, and took notice of this one because of the way it is called.

https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization

Here are the rules for sending a request:

Authentication for Server-Side Applications
Server-side applications must pass two parameters in addition to the apikey parameter:

**ts** - a timestamp (or other long string which can change on a request-by-request basis)

**hash** - a md5 digest of the ts parameter, your private key and your public key (e.g. md5(ts+privateKey+publicKey)

**For example**, a user with a public key of "1234" and a private key of "abcd" could construct a valid call as follows:

**http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=1&apikey=1234&hash=ffd275c5130566a2916217b101f26150**

(the hash value is the md5 digest of 1abcd1234)

#### My Question

How does their server validate such a request? I am using a TIMESTAMP, but it is being hashed - how do they know my request is legit?

So, for fun and games, let's assume we are responsible for validating that call, in - let's say, Javascript (PsuedoCode):

```
/* Grab and Parse Querystring */
let ts = "1";
let publicKey = "1234";  // Public Key
let hash = "ffd275c5130566a2916217b101f26150";  //md5 ts+ privateKey + publicKey

// Ok. now what???
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is a "shared secret", and that is what they're calling the "private key".

Basically, they use the `apikey` parameter to look up what the secret is in their database.  Then, they re-hash to ensure that the hash matches.

The reason for the timestamp is to prevent replay attacks.  However, from what information you're saying, it *doesn't* appear that they're actually validating the request data itself (URL, parameters, etc.).  So, someone who gets a request URL could make other requests with that same hash if they do so quickly.  This is not a very good practice.

Comment: To prevent replay attacks, the `ts` would ideally be replaced with some sort of `nonce` that is required to be different for every request, so that replay attacks are rejected by design.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp and public key are both in the query parameters along with the hash. The server can look up the private key associated with the public key in the request, generate a hash, and compare that with the value you provided.

(The public key and private key are issued by the server as a pair, so it already knows the private key.)